# How to add OCRed text to original pdf in gscan2pdf?

Tags: pdf, ocr

I am new to gscan2pdf 0.9.31, and just used it to OCR a scanned pdf. 
After saving the pdf, the OCRed text is stored on the top left corner. However I wish  each OCRed character to be added to exactly where it was OCRed from, to make the pdf file text-selectable. Can I do that?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is just "no" but I'd love to be wrong.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: `gscan2pdf` does not work in my inputs at all. My test code `gscan2pdf document.pdf`. Then, just use defaults and do full scan. Output: nothing useful. Also in Ubuntu 16.04.